# C++ Having Problems Outputting the number of times a certain character appears in a sentence

Tags: c++, count, character

> Write a program whose input is a character and a string, and whose output indicates the number of times the character appears in the string. The output should include the input character and use the plural form, n's, if the number of times the characters appears is not exactly 1.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> `n Monday`
>
> the output is:
>
> `1 n`
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> `z Today is Monday`
>
> the output is:
>
> `0 z's`
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> `n It's a sunny day`
>
> the output is:
>
> `2 n's`
>
> Case matters.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> `n Nobody`
>
> the output is:
>
> `0 n's`
>
> `n` is different than `N`.

I tried this, and I can't get it to work. Please help me solve this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int CalcNumCharacters(string userString, char userChar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i << userString.length(); i++) {
        if (userString[i] == userChar) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char uchar;
    string ustring;
    cin >> uchar;
    cin >> ustring;

    int counting = CalcNumCharacters(ustring, uchar);
        cout << counting << " " << uchar << "'s" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> ustring` will only read the first word.

Comment: You don't condition whether you print the `'s` or not.

Comment: Your function could just be a call to `std::count()`.

Comment: `i << userString.length()` should be `i < userString.length()`.

Comment: Please be more specific than "can't get it to work". As written, it will not compile due to a stray "}".

Answer (score 2):

To read input that has spaces in it, you need to use `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int CalcNumCharacters(const string &userString, char userChar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); ++i) {
        if (userString[i] == userChar) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char uchar;
    string ustring;

    cin >> uchar;
    getline(cin >> ws, ustring);

    int counting = CalcNumCharacters(ustring, uchar);
    cout << counting << " " << uchar << (counting != 1 ? "'s", "") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am very sorry. I did not see that you put an answer, while I was typing mine. Anyway, I would recommend to add `std::ws` in the `getline` statement, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

C++ input/output operations are more complex than they seem at first glance.

The biggest problem is to understand the difference between *formatted* and *unformatted* input. As you can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), the so-called "extraction" operator `>>` is a *formatted* input function. It reads the characters that you type on your keyboard and "formats" them to the data type that you want.

You may want to read more about that [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction).

One of the caveats is, that the "[extraction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)" operator for strings will stop reading characters if it encounters a so-called "whitespace". That is, for example, a character detected by [`std::isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace).

So, if you enter a sentence like `"Hello world"` and try to read this string with the "extraction" operator `>>`, you will read only `"Hello"`, because `"Hello"` is followed by the whitespace character `' '`.

So, you see that we need to use a different input function for your string. And that is the *unformatted* input function [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). This function will read all characters, until it sees (per default) the `'\n'` (the <kbd>Enter</kbd> character).

OK, fine, then let's use `>>` to read the letter and `std::getline()` to read the sentence. But, unfortunately, there is often the problem when you first read something with a formatted input function and then follow that with an unformatted input function. And the problem is, that the formatted input function will not consume the "whitespace" character after it. This can be a space or a `'\n'` ("Enter") character. And because `std::getline()` stops reading after it sees (as a default) `'\n'`, it will return an empty string.

Let's explain this in an example:

1. You enter a character `'n'` that should be counted
2. Then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
3. Now enter `Hello World`
4. And finally hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key again

On the screen, this will look like

```
n
Hello Word
```

In the background, the following will happen:

- You use the `>>` operator to read a character
- This will (per default) skip leading whitespaces
- The character `n` will be taken out of the input stream and put in your variable `uchar`
- The newline character `'\n'` produced by hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will stay in the input stream
- Now, you try to get the next string with `std::getline()`
- The first thing that `std::getline()` sees is the newline character mentioned above
- And then, nothing will be read into your `ustring` variable

There is a standard solution for that: It is called [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws). This will discard leading whitespace from the input stream (so, in our case, the `'\n'`).

Please remember this for all transitions from formatted to unformatted input.

This will now lead to the first solution with only minor changes to your original source code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int CalcNumCharacters(string userString, char userChar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++) {
        if (userString[i] == userChar) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char uchar;
    string ustring;
    cin >> uchar;
    getline(cin >> ws, ustring);

    int counting = CalcNumCharacters(ustring, uchar);
    cout << counting << " " << uchar << "'s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

But there was an additional requirement. Handling of the "plural" form in your output.

For this, you need to compare the resulting "count" with 1.

- If it is 1, then output no plural
- For any other value, output the plural form

There are many potential solutions, and, most will use the ternary operator `?:` directly in the output insertion statement. I will use an `if` statement for the below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int CalcNumCharacters(string userString, char userChar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++) {
        if (userString[i] == userChar) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char uchar;
    string ustring;
    cin >> uchar;
    getline(cin >> ws, ustring);

    int counting = CalcNumCharacters(ustring, uchar);
    string potentialPlural = "";
    if (counting != 1) {
        potentialPlural = "'s";
    }

    cout << counting << " " << uchar << potentialPlural << endl;
}
```

Comment: How I haven't heard about `std::ws` until now is surprising. I like it a lot better than having to ignore characters.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest mistake is using `std::cin`, because of the `>>`, to read your phrase. It will stop reading at the first whitespace.

You need to use `std::getline()`, but there's a caveat when you mix it with `std::cin`. I'm not going to dive in to why you need to be careful, there are plenty of excellent answers on this site already. Instead, I will demonstrate the use. I will also demonstrate my other comments.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Character: ";
  char letter;
  std::cin >> letter;
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  
  std::cout << "Phrase: ";
  std::string input;
  std::getline(std::cin, input);
  int count = std::ranges::count(input, letter);

  std::cout << count << ' ' << letter
            << (count == 1 ? "\n" : "'s\n");
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
Character: z
Phrase: Today is Monday.
0 z's

~/tmp took 4s 
❯ ./a.out 
Character: n
Phrase: It is sunny.
2 n's

~/tmp took 5s 
❯ ./a.out 
Character: n
Phrase: Monday
1 n
```

This code requires C++20. A fairly simple change will make it compliant down to older standards.

Comment: "*[`std::cin`] will stop reading at the first whitespace... there's a caveat when you mix [`std::getline()`] with `std::cin`*" - More accurately, it is **`operator>>`** that exhibits that behavior, not `std::cin` itself. If your claim were true, then `std::getline()` would not be able to work at all when reading from `std::cin`.

Comment: Also, your code's input doesn't follow the format of the provided instructions. And, you can replace `std::ranges::count()` with `std::count()` in earlier C++ versions.

Comment: I made the note about `std::count`. I also purposely didn't match their format because this is clearly homework. I feel that I clearly addressed the “why” of my answer.  I will edit the one actual error you pointed out.

Comment: All in all, this appears on its face to just disparage my answer to make yours appear better.

Comment: I posted those comments before I posted my own answer.

Comment: That doesn't change my assessment at all. I still pointed out their error. I don't care to do other people’s homework, so I rarely conform to a question’s exact requirements if it means I can still provide an accurate answer.